# Multiple document in the same form with Meteor AutoForm

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I have a few forms that allow the user to add multiple documents to a collection at the same time which I want to convert to use AutoForm but I can't work how best to do it.

For example, the user can create a class in a school.  A class can have a name, subject and teacher.  Instead of a form to add just one class at a time I have rows which allow adding many classes at the same time. Here's a simple example how it looks before I add AutoForm.  This gives me three rows with a name, subject and teacher column in each row.

```
<form class="class-form">
    <div class="table-row">
        <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="name">
        <input type="text" name="subject[]" placeholder="subject">
        <input type="text" name="teacher[]" placeholder="teacher">
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
        <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="name">
        <input type="text" name="subject[]" placeholder="subject">
        <input type="text" name="teacher[]" placeholder="teacher">
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
        <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="name">
        <input type="text" name="subject[]" placeholder="subject">
        <input type="text" name="teacher[]" placeholder="teacher">
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

I can create a schema for a class and use AutoForm to create a form for one class at a time, but how can I use AutoForm to create multiple documents in one form as above?

[The example code  has been simplified a lot here.  It uses Select2 elements to choose subject and teacher and there are more fields and s in the actual code.  Also, as the rows fill up I automatically add more rows.  I'm keeping this example simple and will tackle those problems later]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible to insert multiple documents on one form, however you can add arrays of sub documents in one form such as:

```
ClassesCollection = new Mongo.Collection("classes");


ClassSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    subject: {
        type: String
    },
    teacher: {
        type: String
    }
});


ClassesSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    classes: {
        type: [ClassSchema]
    }
});

ClassesCollection.attachSchema(ClassSchema);
```

That will generate a form for you where you can add multiple classes at once, however they will all be stored in one document under a "classes" array. This might be an unwelcome change to your architecture. So you could either extend autoForm to have that functionality or stick with your custom solution.

Comment: I can't have them all as an array in one document, but I could use `ClassesSchema` to make AutoForm create the correct form and then instead of having a `ClassesCollection` I would process the form myself and add each class to the `ClassCollection`.  But most probably I just won't be able to use AutoForm.  I don't think I have the time to extend AutoForm to support this.

Comment: I eventually decided to stick to my custom solution and use Collections2 without AutoForm.